# R;Too slow to overate loops for million vectors

Tags: r

I'm managing with a data table. I have 13 * 2598893  data table, and I'm trying to make new column filled with character calculated based on another column.
 So i made a function, and applied it to 'for in' loops, with those millions of rows. And it takes forever! I waited for some minutes, and I could not distinguish it from system down.

I tried it for just 10 rows, and the loops and function works well fastly. But when I extend it to other rows, it takes forever, again.

```
str(eco)
'data.frame':   2598893 obs. of  13 variables:
```

made function like this

```
check<-function(x){
  if(x<=15){
    return(1)
  }
  else{
    return(0)
  }
}
```

And applied loops like this.

```
for(x in c(1:nrow(eco))){eco[x,13]<-check(eco[x,4])}
```

And it continues and continues to work.

How can I shorten this work? Or is this just the limit of R that I should endure?

Comment: `eco[,13] <- ifelse(eco[,4] <= 15, 1, 0)`

Comment: As long as you are looking for a binary outcome {0, 1}, may be even faster to do this directly: `eco[, 13L] <- as.integer(eco[, 4L] <= 15)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should probably try to vectorize your operations (NB: `for` loops can often times be avoided in R). In addition, you could check out the `data.table` package to further improve efficiency:

```r
library(data.table)

set.seed(1)

## create data.table
eco <- as.data.table(matrix(sample(1:100, 13 * 2598893, replace = TRUE), ncol = 13))

## update column
system.time(
    set(eco, j = 13L, value = 1 * (eco[[4]] <= 15))
)
#>    user  system elapsed 
#>   0.018   0.016   0.033

eco
#>          V1 V2  V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10 V11 V12 V13
#>       1: 68 74  55 62 82 51 42 18 16  12  50  73   0
#>       2: 39 97  53 61 21 25 79 71 85  19  54  30   0
#>       3:  1 89  62 42  5 90 33 77 31   1  59  26   0
#>       4: 34 22  27  4 36 74 65 45 46  67  74  34   1
#>       5: 87 57  88  4 42 26  9 13 64  32  16  15   1
#>      ---                                            
#> 2598889: 91 59  78 28 98 98 13 87 88  46  66  85   0
#> 2598890: 82 60  87 60 49 25 10  9 97  78  61  91   0
#> 2598891: 19  2 100 75 66 88 12 46 94  32  69  56   0
#> 2598892: 18 47  22 87 23 79 56 99 13  29  15  46   0
#> 2598893: 47 30   8  8  9 80 49 78 20  43  86  11   1
```